# Using a timer to delay a char[] from displaying all characters at once

Tags: c#

I'm having a little bit of trouble figuring out the best way to display 1 character at a time on the console using a timer. The idea is to have an RPG style message stream across the screen instead of being pasted all at once.

```
    private static System.Timers.Timer aTimer;

    public void DisplayTime()
    {

        aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(5000);
        aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);

        aTimer.AutoReset = false;
        aTimer.Enabled = true;

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        string text;
        text = "This is a test";
        char[] message = new char[text.Length];
        message = text.ToCharArray();

        for (int i = 0; i < message.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.Write(message[i]);
        }
    }
```

That is what I currently have which just delays displaying the message for 5 seconds. I'm trying to avoid using Thread.Sleep if possible because from what I've read that is a big no no. I know I need to create a delay in the for loop to get the effect i need but is this really the best way to go about it?

Comment: Using Thread.Sleep() really doesn't matter in a console app.  It's only evil in a GUI app, the kind that stays responsive to user input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a great place for using a lambda.

```
public void DisplayTime(string message) {
  var index = 0;
  var timer = new System.Timers.Timer(5000);
  timer.Elapsed += delegate { 
    if (index < message.Length) {
      Console.Write(message[index]);
      index++;
    } else {
      timer.Enabled = false;
      timer.Dispose();
    }
  };
  timer.Enabled = true;
}
```

Now you can just call `DisplayTime("the message")` and it will slowly write out the message one character every 5 seconds and clean up the timer when it's finished

Answer (score 2):

Use `Thread.Sleep()`.  It will provide just what you need for, without any drawbacks for you.  What you heard about `Sleep()` is completely out of context and it doesn't apply to your situation.

Answer (score 1):

You need to keep track of where you are in your character stream - It seems like you want to display just one character at a time and then pause a little, until you have displayed all characters. A timer would be perfect for this - you will have to keep track of the message and the current position in the message as instance variables though:

```
private int messagePosition = 0;
private string message = "This is a test";;
public void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    if(messagePosition < message.Length)
    {
        Console.Write(message[messagePosition]);
        messagePosition++;  
    }
    else 
      aTimer.Enabled = false;
}
```